# Funnel query with Amazon Redshift / PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, analytics, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to analyze a funnel using event data in Redshift and have difficulties finding an efficient query to extract that data.

For example, in Redshift I have:

```
timestamp          action        user id
---------          ------        -------
2015-05-05 12:00   homepage      1
2015-05-05 12:01   product page  1
2015-05-05 12:02   homepage      2
2015-05-05 12:03   checkout      1
```

I would like to extract the funnel statistics. For example:

```
homepage_count  product_page_count  checkout_count
--------------  ------------------  --------------
100             50                  25
```

Where `homepage_count` represent the distinct number of users who visited the homepage, `product_page_count` represents the distinct numbers of users who visited the homepage **after** visiting the homepage, and `checkout_count` represents the number of users who checked out after visiting the homepage and the product page.

What would be the best query to achieve that with Amazon Redshift? Is it possible to do with a single query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best method might be to add flags to the data for the first visit of each type for each user and then use these for aggregation logic:

```
select sum(case when ts_homepage is not null then 1 else 0 end) as homepage_count,
       sum(case when ts_productpage > ts_homepage then 1 else 0 end) as productpage_count,
       sum(case when ts_checkout > ts.productpage and ts.productpage > ts.homepage then 1 else 0 end) as checkout_count
from (select userid,
             min(case when action = 'homepage' then timestamp end) as ts_homepage,
             min(case when action = 'product page' then timestamp end) as ts_productpage,
             min(case when action = 'checkout' then timestamp end) as ts_checkout
      from table t
      group by userid
     ) t
```

Comment: Does it also cover the case when the checkout happens after visiting the product page but not after visiting the homepage?

Comment: Shouldn't the last condition be `case when ts_checkout > ts_productpage and ts_productpage> ts_homepage then 1 else 0 end`?

Comment: @lta . . . It does now. ;)

Comment: I also posted a similar question about retention tables.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30698175/cohort-analysis-with-amazon-redshift-postgressql

Comment: @Gordon Linoff can you explain how does it cover all the cases as described by @Ita?

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is very much correct . I have modified it for people using it for AWS Mobile Analytics and Redshift.

```
 select sum(case when ts_homepage is not null then 1 else 0 end) as homepage_count,
   sum(case when ts_productpage > ts_homepage then 1 else 0 end) as productpage_count,
   sum(case when ts_checkout > ts_productpage and ts_productpage > ts_homepage then 1 else 0 end) as checkout_count
from (select client_id,
         min(case when event_type = 'App Launch' then event_timestamp end) as ts_homepage,
         min(case when event_type = 'SignUp Success' then event_timestamp end) as ts_productpage,
         min(case when event_type = 'Start Quiz' then event_timestamp end) as ts_checkout
  from awsma.v_event
  group by client_id
 ) ts;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case more precise model required: when product page can be opened twice. First time before home page and second one after. This case usually should be considered as conversion as well.

Redshift SQL query:

```
SELECT
COUNT(
 DISTINCT CASE WHEN cur_homepage_time IS NOT NULL
 THEN user_id END
) Step1,
COUNT(
DISTINCT CASE WHEN cur_homepage_time IS NOT NULL AND cur_productpage_time IS NOT NULL
  THEN user_id END
) Step2,
COUNT(
DISTINCT CASE WHEN
  cur_homepage_time IS NOT NULL AND cur_productpage_time IS NOT NULL AND cur_checkout_time IS NOT NULL
  THEN user_id END
) Step3
FROM (
   SELECT
     user_id,
     timestamp,
     COALESCE(homepage_time,
              LAG(homepage_time) IGNORE NULLS OVER(PARTITION BY user_id
              ORDER BY time)
     ) cur_homepage_time,
     COALESCE(productpage_time,
              LAG(productpage_time) IGNORE NULLS OVER(PARTITION BY distinct_id
              ORDER BY time)
     ) cur_productpage_time,
     COALESCE(checkout_time,
              LAG(checkout_time) IGNORE NULLS OVER(PARTITION BY distinct_id
              ORDER BY time)
     ) cur_checkout_time
   FROM
     (
       SELECT
         timestamp,
         user_id,
         (CASE WHEN event = 'homepage'
           THEN timestamp END) homepage_time,
         (CASE WHEN event = 'product page'
           THEN timestamp END) productpage_time,
         (CASE WHEN event = 'checkout'
           THEN timestamp END) checkout_time
       FROM events
       WHERE timestamp > '2016-05-01' AND timestamp < '2017-01-01'
       ORDER BY user_id, timestamp
     ) event_times
   ORDER BY user_id, timestamp
 ) event_windows
```

This query fills each row's `cur_homepage_time`, `cur_productpage_time` and `cur_checkout_time` with recent timestamp of event occurrences. So in case for some specific time (read row) event occured then particular column is not `NULL`.

More info [here](https://blog.statsbot.co/sql-queries-for-funnel-analysis-35d5e456371d).