# Retention cohort with active user conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

This question is an extension of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30698175/cohort-analysis-with-amazon-redshift-postgressql)..
The user wishes to do cohort analysis of retention.
The data is in following format:

```
timestamp          action        user id
---------          ------        -------
2015-05-05 12:00   homepage      1
2015-05-05 12:01   product page  1
2015-05-05 12:02   homepage      2
2015-05-05 12:03   checkout      1
```

The necessary output is as following:

```
signup_date  user_period  retained_users
-----------  -----------  --------------
2015-05-05   0            80
2015-05-05   1            60
2015-05-05   2            40
2015-05-05   3            20
2015-05-06   0            100
2015-05-06   1            80
2015-05-06   2            40
2015-05-06   3            20
```

The answer was figured out by the same person and is as below..

```
 WITH 
users AS (
  SELECT
    user_id,
    date_trunc('day', min(timestamp)) as activated_at
    from table
    group by 1
  )
,

events AS (
  SELECT user_id,
         action,
         timestamp AS occurred_at
    FROM table
)

SELECT DATE_TRUNC('day',u.activated_at) AS signup_date,


       TRUNC(EXTRACT('EPOCH' FROM e.occurred_at - u.activated_At)/(3600*24)) AS user_period,


       COUNT(DISTINCT e.user_id) AS retained_users
  FROM users u
  JOIN events e
    ON e.user_id = u.user_id
   AND e.occurred_at >= u.activated_at
 WHERE u.activated_at >= getdate() - INTERVAL '11 day'
 GROUP BY 1,2
 ORDER BY 1,2
```

In the above case as far as I understand if a user just performs any single event.. s/he will be considered active. and will be part of retained_users.

But, in my scenario.. I wish to decide who an active user is..

so an active user could be someone who either views 5 pages OR views atleast 3 product pages OR adds one product to cart OR does a checkout and so on..

How do I do something like this..

I guess the events AS(..) section will have to be changed..

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you try to put the entire question in a explanation?  I really don't know what you are looking for, with the cross references and the query that isn't quite relevant.

Comment: @GordonLinoff In the above question.. you have the inputdata structure and output data structure.. Both of them are to be same in my case.. The only difference I have is I wish to decide who an active user is unlike the original question..